# Mediawiki error: Lua error in package.lua at line 80: module 'strict' not found

Tags: templates, module, lua, mediawiki, strict

I'm try to install Mediawiki on local host, and working with Lua. I try to export one page from Wikipedia, for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maize, and  re-import it into the local system.

One critical error appeared as "Lua error in package.lua at line 80: module 'strict' not found."! I try to import multiple Module/Template, but the error is always still there!

**Wiki source code:
**

```
{{about|the commonly grown cereal grain}}

{{redirect|Corn}}

{{Speciesbox
| name = Maize
| image = Koeh-283.jpg
| image_caption = Illustration showing male and female maize flowers
| genus = Zea (plant)
| species = mays
| status = LC
| status_system = IUCN3.1
| status_ref = <ref>Contreras, A., Ruíz Corral, J.A., Menjívar, J., Aragón Cuevas, F., González Ledesma, M. & Sánchez, J.J. 2019. Zea mays. The IUCN Red List of Threatened Species 2019: e.T77726273A77726310. https://dx.doi.org/10.2305/IUCN.UK.2019-2.RLTS.T77726273A77726310.en. Accessed on 28 October 2022.</ref>
| authority = [[Carl Linnaeus|L.]]
}}
```

**Error:**

```
Lua error in package.lua at line 80: module 'strict' not found.
Lua error in package.lua at line 80: module 'strict' not found.
Koeh-283.jpg
Illustration showing male and female maize flowers
Conservation status

Least Concern (IUCN 3.1)[1]
Scientific classificationedit
Species: Lua error in package.lua at line 80: module 'strict' not found.Z. mays
Binomial name
Lua error in package.lua at line 80: module 'strict' not found.Zea mays
L.
```

If there is any solution, please share it! Thank you!

I try to export multiple modules and templates from Wikipedia and import them into the local system, but not efficient!

Answer (score 2):

`require('strict')` is a newly added [Scribunto](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto) functionality, replacing the usage of the [No globals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module:No_globals) module on Wikipedia. For more information, see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto/Lua_reference_manual#Strict_library and https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T209310.

You can either import older versions of the modules, or update your installation of the Scribunto extension.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! That helps me to understand the reasons of errors. I think about two solutions but I don't have enough experiency: (1) Import the older versions of the modules as your suggests, (2) When importing the Templates from Wikipedia, re-changing the prefix of Template into the local scope of the local host? How do you think about these solutions?

Comment: Importing older versions and Module:No globals would make more sense.